# datagridview loop through all colums for values

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview like the below. I am looping through each Column and checking to see if the values is true. If Grade Column = A then it places Name and the grade value into 1 datagridview and if the Grade Column = F then it places it into another datagridview .  There is however a slight issue it produces false data if more than one row is populated in the datagridview . Is there a way where I can ensure that one row is showing when they use the below function(such as rowselected)  or somehow loop through the column then each row accordingly. In my actual table there are over 100 columns that I am searching for A and F as well so I cannot just use loop through each row for some specific cell.

> Personid, Name, Grade, 99Grade, 20Grade
>       1, bob, A, A, F
>       2, Sam, F, F, A
>       3, Kristen, A, A, F

```
For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

        If dt.Rows(0).Item(column) = myFirstValue Then

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(column.ColumnName, dt.Rows(i)(1))
                Next
            End If
        End If

        If dt.Rows(0).Item(column) = mySecondValue Then
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    Form2.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(column.ColumnName, dt.Rows(i)(1))
                Next
            End If
        End If

    Next column
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I figures out how to select One row rather than all Rows. In case anyone else want it.

```
For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

If dt.Rows(0).Item(column) = myFirstValue Then

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then or Each lRow As DataGridViewRow In  DataGridView1.SelectedRows                  
Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(column.ColumnName, lRow.Cells(0).Value))
            Next
        End If
    End If

    If dt.Rows(0).Item(column) = mySecondValue Then
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
For Each lRow As DataGridViewRow In  DataGridView1.SelectedRows
Form2.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(column.ColumnName,  lRow.Cells(0).Value)
            Next
        End If
    End If

Next column
```